# SQL Server - Create a new database for a user and ONLY give them access / view rights to that one DB

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have admin rights on a SQL Server 2012 Server and have a user that wants me to create a "throw away" database for them on the server.
Basically, I'm looking to:

1. Create this database
2. Give the user full access / rights TO ONLY THAT DATABASE
3. Have them see it and its schema - but not any other DBs - in the SSMS Object Explorer

I've found quite a few answers around online and the one that got me closest was this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400392/1693085

Basically giving me these lines of SQL to execute:

```
--Step 1: (create a new user)
create LOGIN hello WITH PASSWORD='foo', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;


-- Step 2:(deny view to any database)
USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO hello; 


 -- step 3 (then authorized the user for that specific database , you have to use the  master by doing use master as below)
USE master;
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::yourDB TO hello;
GO
```

However, when I then log in as this user and right click on a created table, I get the following error repeated dozens of times:

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regread', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

And, if I ignore it and try and delete the table anyways, I get basically the same error again.

All I basically want to do is create a user and ensure they have no more access than that one database, but have full access on that one...

Am I doing something wrong / What should I change??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in your linked post?  First deny the user rights to view databases, then drop the user in your database, then make the login the db owner.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, I did... I still get that error message, though... Any thoughts why??

Comment: Did you try granting permission to that sp?

Comment: To that sp?? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Oh, ok - got it... I'll try that now....

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, It worked! - I used the SQL from this site: https://blog.itrio.net/2013/09/04/how-to-configure-permissions-for-xp_regread-and-xp_instance_regread/ - If you'd like to post that up as a solution, I'd happily give you credit for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by granting the user permission to the stored procedure:

```
USE master
GO

GRANT EXEC ON OBJECT::master.dbo.xp_instance_regread TO hello
GO
```