# How to set password for SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, passwords

How do I set up a database so that one does not have access to it? Even with installing SQL Server Management Studio on local machine.

In SQL Server  with  Windows user or `sa` can access all databases. How do you limit the access DB of the users?

For assuming that SQL Server is installed on the local machine, not on the server

Comment: Open up security in SSMS, right click on any user and set the mappings and access. Is this not what you want?

Comment: It depends on what permissions you want your users to have. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085700/restrict-sql-server-login-access-to-only-one-database

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Single User Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx).

From the linked MSDN article:

> Single-user mode specifies that only one user at a time can access the database and is generally used for maintenance actions.

---

**Edit**: You edited your question. Now it sounds more like you're asking about [Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669084(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of how to limit the database to one user.

You can edit a user's security in SQL Server Management Studio by drilling down into Security > Logins. There you will see all logins to your instance. You can right click these entries and select Properties to made updates. The easiest way to completely bar a user from accessing any of the databases on the server is by selecting "Disabled" from the "Status" tab.

Comment: no, I do not mean this .
I want sa does not have access to the database.

Comment: You can find "sa" listed as a Login in SSMS. You can follow the steps I outlined to disable it from logging in.

Comment: Why would you want to do that @AlenSmith ? It only needs to be done once. Use TSQL

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to limit this to just one user, there is a simple way (but a bit risky).

Your Windows user is included in the group `BuiltinAdministrators`. If you really want to remove your Windows user, rerun the installation process and during the setup just change the users in those group.

But beware, you should provide another user, which has access to your database otherwise you end up with a database server without access to it.

Ater that, setup a database login and grant him access to the database you desire.

In the end, you can disable the `sa` login. This will prevent access with the sa account. But you should have a user which can manage logins and more. Otherwise you have no chance to recreate the password or any other administrative tasks.