# how to: prevent sql server user from creating more databases

Tags: sql-server, permissions

This Answer here: [Restricts SQL Server Login access to only one database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400392/44080)

That works fine, but the user can still create databases.

Please how do we **restrict a user from creating databases**.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be a `DDL` trigger: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1468082-391-1.aspx

Comment: @Ralph is there no rule or restriction we can set to prevent new database creation?

Comment: What are the roles for these new logins? I am guessing that these are no ordinary logins since (by default) no login has any such permissions. Just give it a try: `create login test with password = N'test'; execute as login = N'test'; create database dbTest;` should yield an error. Yet you could try `deny create any database to test;` as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182763.aspx But then you need to ensure that these logins cannot change their own permissions again.