# Particular Database Security In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to secure my particular database in SQL server.How to do?
I have create new  SQL user profile and follow all steps database but can not hide other databases.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information to help people to help you. When you say "not working" in what way is it not working? I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then coming back and editing your question to add further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect to your SQL server instance using management studio
2. Goto Security -> Logins -> (RIGHT CLICK) New Login
3. fill in user details
4. Under User Mapping, select the databases you want the user to be
   able to access and configure

**NOTE**: You'll also want to go to Security -> Server Roles, and for "public" check the permissions for TSQL Default TCP/TSQL Default VIA/TSQL Local Machine/TSQL Named Pipes and remove the "connect" permission.

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Comment: I have done these steps but not restricting.thanks for reply

Comment: check [Restrict SQL Server Login access to only one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085700/restrict-sql-server-login-access-to-only-one-database)

Comment: it is working now