# Hide all but one database in SQL Management Studio for a specific user without owner privilege

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Manager, we want a user to only see a specific database without giving him db_owner privileges. We already tried around with `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO test CASCADE`, but that hides all databases. To let the database appear in the database list again, I read that we should give him db_owner rights. But that's not what we want.

Is there a way to specify on a per-user basis, which databases he or she could see in the list without admin privileges?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict SQL Server Login access to only one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085700/restrict-sql-server-login-access-to-only-one-database)

Comment: Unfortunately no. The solution provided there sets the user as db_owner.

Comment: It's all, or nothing I'm afraid. But being able to *see* a database exists doesn't actually mean that can *do* anything with it.

Comment: @Larnu We want to use the SSMS as a temporary provisional solution for a DAU. The user should only be able to make changes to certain tables in this particular database as long as the corresponding user interface has not been completely programmed. Hence the question how we can make the whole thing as easy and self-explanatory as possible.

Comment: Just because they can see the other database, doesn't mean that they can actually see "inside" them, @AndréReichelt . Like I said.

Comment: @Larnu There are about fifty databases on the server. We simply wanted to make the confusion as small as possible for the user.