# SQL Server grant SQL Agent access for a user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I needed to hide the unwanted databased from the users and allow only the relevant databased to view. I've managed to do it with the help of the answers provided in [Restrict SQL Server Login access to only one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085700/restrict-sql-server-login-access-to-only-one-database)
with following query

```
    --Step 1: (create a new user)
create LOGIN <<UserName>> WITH PASSWORD='<<Password>>', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;

-- Step 2:(deny view to any database)
USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <<UserName>>; 

  --step 3 (then authorized the user for that specific database , you have to use the  master by doing use master as below)
USE master;
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<<DBName>> TO <<UserName>>;
GO
```

Now a sql server login created from above script wanted to access the SQL Agent to schedule and execute sql server Jobs. I've given the permissions shown in below image to the sql server login created. But it's not working.
[image]

If I make the user a SysAdmin then the permissions were granted. But then it will show all the databased. Not only the allowed ones.

How can I give the SQL Server Agent access to a user login created with only given database wisibility.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? *Also, SQL Server 2008 has been end of life for 18 months~; you should really be looking at upgrade paths by now.*

Comment: Not working means The SQL Server Agent is not available. Even though I have given the permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by "not available"? If Agent isn't running that has nothing to do with the permissions you gave.