# Create a SQL login that can only list and read from only allowed databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I know it is easy to limit a sql user to be able to read from only certain databases by adding the user to the db_datareader role in the specified database(s). But is there a way to set some permission so that the user is only able to list the databases(s) they are allowed to read from. For example if I have n number of databases in a server, how do I create a login such that they would only be able to see one database when they login using ssms or some other tool.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085744/2067753

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400392/2067753

Comment: The answers in those posts are helpful, but they don't solve the problem. The line `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::yourDB TO hello;` makes the `hello` user the owner of the database essentially giving them all read write access. I only want to give them read access.